# How to convert string to Time(dataType) field in apex

Tags: apex

I was trying to convert string to Time datatype in apex, any one help on this would be great.

Salesforce recently come up with new datatypes `Time`, `URL`. I was using the Time datatype and am unable to convert string value to Time.

Error:

> Illegal assignment from String to Time error

Code:

```
APS_Treatment__c treat = [SELECT Id, APS_Start_Date__c, APS_Time1__c, 
    APS_Time_1__c FROM APS_Treatment__c WHERE Id = :TreatId]; 

DateTime appTime = treat.APS_Start_Date__c; 
appTime = appTime.addhours(treat.APS_Time_1__c.hour()); 
appTime = appTime.addminutes(treat.APS_Time_1__c.minute()); 
String sd = String.valueOf(appTime.format('hh:mm:ss\'z\'')); 
treat.APS_Time_1__c = sd; 
update treat;
```

Comment: You would need to first convert string to date time then add time, or there is also new instance method? Could you update your question with some code snippet?

Comment: APS_Treatment__c treat = [SELECT Id,APS_Start_Date__c,APS_Time1__c, APS_Time_1__c FROM APS_Treatment__c WHERE Id=:TreatId];
DateTime appTime = treat.APS_Start_Date__c;
appTime = appTime.addhours(treat.APS_Time_1__c.hour());
appTime = appTime.addminutes(treat.APS_Time_1__c.minute()); 
String sd = String.valueOf(appTime.format('hh:mm:ss\'z\''));
treat.APS_Time_1__c = sd;
Update treat;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Time.newInstance`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_time.htm#apex_methods_system_time) method to construct the Time from Date time:

Example:

```
DateTime dt = System.today();
Time myTime = Time.newInstance(dt.hour(), dt.minute(), dt.second(), dt.millisecond());
```

Your code needs to be modified as:

```
APS_Treatment__c treat = [SELECT Id, APS_Start_Date__c, APS_Time1__c, 
    APS_Time_1__c FROM APS_Treatment__c WHERE Id = :TreatId]; 

DateTime appTime = treat.APS_Start_Date__c; 
treat.APS_Time_1__c = 
    Time.newInstance(
        appTime.hour(), 
        appTime.minute(), 
        appTime.second(), 
        appTime.millisecond()); 
update treat;
```

Comment: Thanq for Quick reply.When a record is created from IOS Mobile, Time is saving in UTC. But wen i see it in sfdc the time is in GMT. I want to make the Time field is same in both IOS app and Desktop.

Comment: Your query is not related to your original question. Please log a new one if you are unable to find it, and do not forget to accept the best answer to help others looking for same problem.

Comment: This answer might solve the question author problem, but does not answer how to convert string to a Time object in the absence of valueOf() method